# ASP.NET DropDownList OnItemDataBound

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a method on a `<asp:DropDownList>` that is equivalent to the OnItemDataBound on Repeaters?

The reason is I want to check each value before putting it in the drop down list.

Comment: Can't you check the values before putting in the drop down list?

Comment: I'd insert them manually one by one

Answer (score 1):

Nothing similar to OnItemDataBound  which will give you an item context.There are events like OnDataBound which will get triggered when it reaches binding.

Your reason for asking this event is for enriching the row instead to filterout, which would not have helped you even with this event.

The best option to solve your question

> The reason is I want to check each value before putting it in the drop
>   down list.

is to do some thing like the following pseudo code

```
this.YourDropDownList.Items.Clear(); 
var lst = new List<ListItem>();
var yourCollection= <YOURCollection after Apply Linq Conditions check>
foreach (var obj in yourCollection)
{ //loop and add 
  this.YourDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem {Text = obj.Prop1, Value = obj.prop2});
}
```